# How to write a fluent constraint in NUnit that requires parenthesis

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, fluent-interface

I recently started working with the Constraint functionality of NUnit and ran into the following question. How can I write a constraint using the fluent expression syntax where the order of execution is important and in normal C# programming is solved with parenthesis?

In the following example I define two separate assertions:

1. A string should start with 1 or 2 and in all cases the string should end with 5
2. A string should start with 1 or 2, and in the cases where the string starts with 2 it should end with 5

To assert this, I can think about three ways; classic, fluent constraints and constraints using compound constraints. So this results in 6 tests and some test cases.

```
private class SourceForParenthesisTest : IEnumerable
{
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData("2").Throws(typeof(AssertionException));
        yield return new TestCaseData("3").Throws(typeof(AssertionException));
        yield return new TestCaseData("15");
        yield return new TestCaseData("25");
        yield return new TestCaseData("35").Throws(typeof(AssertionException));
    }
}

[TestCase("1", ExpectedException = typeof(AssertionException))]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(SourceForParenthesisTest))]
public void WithParenthesisClassic(string i)
{
    var res = (i.StartsWith("1") || i.StartsWith("2")) && i.EndsWith("5");
    Assert.True(res);
}

[TestCase("1", ExpectedException = typeof(AssertionException))]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(SourceForParenthesisTest))]
public void WithParenthesisOperatorConstraint(string i)
{
    Assert.That(i, (Is.StringStarting("1") | Is.StringStarting("2")) & Is.StringEnding("5"));
}

[TestCase("1", ExpectedException = typeof(AssertionException), Ignore = true, IgnoreReason = "Not clear how to write this fluent expression")]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(SourceForParenthesisTest))]
public void WithParenthesisConstraint(string i)
{
    Assert.That(i, Is.StringStarting("1").Or.StringStarting("2").And.StringEnding("5"));
}

[TestCase("1")]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(SourceForParenthesisTest))]
public void NoParenthesisClassic(string i)
{
    var res = i.StartsWith("1") || i.StartsWith("2") && i.EndsWith("5");
    Assert.True(res);
}

[TestCase("1")]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(SourceForParenthesisTest))]
public void NoParenthesisOperatorConstraint(string i)
{
    Assert.That(i, Is.StringStarting("1") | Is.StringStarting("2") & Is.StringEnding("5"));
}

[TestCase("1")]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(SourceForParenthesisTest))]
public void NoParenthesisConstraint(string i)
{
    Assert.That(i, Is.StringStarting("1").Or.StringStarting("2").And.StringEnding("5"));
}
```

The actual problem is in WithParenthesisConstraint (assert 1 as listed above), I couldn't think about a way how to write the constraint correctly and this results in one failing test case that I have set to ignored.

How do I write this assert to work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see an obvious way to do this either. My first thought is that you need to resolve the expression up to a given point, which leave's your assertion looking like this:

```
Assert.That(i, ((IResolveConstraint)Is.StringStarting("1").Or.StringStarting("2"))
                                      .Resolve().With.StringEnding("5"))
```

Which is obviously a bit messy.  You can add your own extension method to make it a bit more pleasant, using something like this (you can obviously rename the extension method to anything you think is appropriate):

```
static class MyExtensions {
    public static Constraint Evaluate(this Constraint exp) {           
        return ((IResolveConstraint)exp).Resolve();
    }
}
```

Which would make your test code assertion this:

```
Assert.That(i, (Is.StringStarting("1").Or.StringStarting("2")).Evaluate()
                                      .And.StringEnding("5"));
```

Which is a bit nicer but isn't ideal so may not be what you're looking for.

It may also be worth considering combining the `Evaluate` and `And` constraints to make it easier to read.  Perhaps an extension method like this:

```
public static ConstraintExpression OnlyIf(this Constraint exp) {
    return ((IResolveConstraint)exp).Resolve().And;
}
```

To give test code like this:

```
Assert.That(i, (Is.StringStarting("1").Or.StringStarting("2")).OnlyIf()
                                                              .StringEnding("5"));
```